# MATLAB: times function undefined for table. How do I get around it?

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I am trying to create a simple linear regression model. a.csv contains 8 columns. Var1 month dow Hour is_holiday T load Date. I get an error at X = ones... it says undefined unction times for input arguments of type table.

```
 T = readtable('a.csv')
    x1 = T(:, 6);
    x2 = T(:,3);
    y = T(:,7);
    X = [ones(size(x1)) x1 x2 x1.*x2];
    b = regress(y,X)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you slice a table with indexing, in Matlab, you obtain another table, but with a smaller number of rows or columns... so in this part of code:

```
x1 .* x2
```

you are trying to multiply two tables together.

If you open your `T` variable from the workspace window, you should notice that the table defines one header name for each column like `Var1`, `Var2`, ... `VarN` (which corresponds to your first CSV row value, if defined, or defaulted as above). If you want to use the underlying strong typed vectors of your table, you have to call:

```
T.VarX
```

Let's suppose that your `x1` corresponds to `T.Var1`, `x2` to `T.Var2` and your `y` references `T.Var3` then:

```
X = [ones(size(x1)) T.Var1 T.Var2 (T.Var1 .* T.Var2)];
% ...
b = regress(T.Var3,X)
```

This way, you don't even need to slice your table.